# Lists and brackets

Tags: r

I'm new to R and trying to understand a few things about lists. Say I have the following:

```
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee")
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
x = list(n, s, b, 3)
```

I understand the following (I think) because I'm asking R to return the second list of values (because I'm using single brackets).

```
x[2]
# [[1]]
# [1] "aa" "bb" "cc" "dd" "ee"
```

This I don't understand because I'm using double brackets which is supposed to return a single value. Actually, I'm not what I would expect R should return here. I'm asking for a single value but the second group of objects is another list.

```
x[[2]]
# [1] "aa" "bb" "cc" "dd" "ee"
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi - I did take a look. "[[" selects a single element. So why is it returning five elements?

Comment: @RandyMinder This list is composed of vectors -- the "list elements" are vectors.  `[[` is returning a single vector.  `[` returns another list of vector or vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using the exact example found [here](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list), although perhaps this is a common list example.

In essence, `x[2]` is a "slice", which is a `list` of length 1 that contains the second item of x. `x[[2]]` *is* the second item of x. You can verify this with `class(x[2])` and `class(x[[2]])`.

Answer (score -1):

`X` has become a list of lists.  If you just run `x` you should get all of its elements, then the `x[[2]]` result should make sense.

To get the first element of the second list, try `x[[2]][1]` which is saying "the first object in the second list of object x."

Another helpful trick in R is to use `str(x)` which shows you the structure of the object, in this case the type of lists and their contents.

Comment: I guess my major confusion here is why x[2] and x[[2]] return the exact same thing. They perform different operations.

Comment: @RandyMinder - the `x` `list` you have has 4 single sub-structures, which are also `list`s. `x[[2]]` selects a **single** sub-structure, which is equivalent to the second `list` stored in `x`

Comment: But @RandyMinder, `x[2]` and `x[[2]]` do not return the same thing: one is a vector of five chars, one is a list with one element, that element being a vector with of five chars. Accessing this list is similar to [Inception](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/): `x[2]` is the same as `x[2][1]` same as `x[2][1][1][1][1]`, etc, and it is very important to see why this happens like it does with lists.

Comment: @r2evans - Your explanation really helped. If you type this up as an answer, I'll accept it.